# Radical cultural change with strict adherence to tradition?

Tags: discussion, moderation, site-promotion

It completely surprises me, how a group of very strict StackExchange traditionalists, who want to adhere to every single rules to the letter, are trying to start a discussion about a radical cultural change in the processes and methods of doing things in a new way.

How detail oriented optimization of every single aspect of the site individually and apart, trying to find the best moderation box in every single case on its own and in every question as it stands alone, does not seem to be in the minds of the group at odds with the topic at hand, which is promoting systems thinking and view of the entire system as a whole with all the interdependency and complexity.

How a culture that is supposed to promote blamelessness, openness and bridging the gaps and divisions between disciplines and departments is discussed by people who are extremely quick to judge and close minded to anything that does not fit their strict view of the world from their singular view point and viewed through lenses of their particular experience.

Do we even stand a chance? Are we even capable to apply any of the lessons we preach?

Comment: Interesting that you're in favor of a blameless culture while looping over blaming peoples only.

Answer (score 3):

Any change needs to start *somewhere*. Cultural changes in particular are in a really bad spot initially because they have to at least partially invalidate an established scale of values or practices. Which many won't accept easily (or even at all), at least at the beginning.

I'm just a bit surprised that you are surprised to encounter resistance ;) My suggestion is to not take it at heart. Many of those trying to embrace DevOps don't quite know how - they're still used with the old ways. But they try. And some succeed. DevOps is about making that happen. But patience, inclusion and communication are keys.

A similar thing happens here: yes, there are rules for SE sites. And no one has been successful in doing an SE site like the one you're expecting. So no one knows exactly if creating such site is possible and, if it is, how it's done.

So just give it a bit more time - we've only been in (private) beta for less then 3 weeks and we have less than 100 members actually active, other site have been in beta for years and have 100s/1000s of members.

Test the flexibility of the boundaries - ask the questions you'd like to ask. Don't get upset if they're not well received presently. Most likely those that can change didn't have enough time to do so. And if the current majority won't get swayed don't despair - that majority is too small to be representative for the future community. But once the audience grows significantly maybe others would like them too.

Same DevOps keys apply: patience, inclusion and communication.

My 2c.